# Reordering a list from the ends towards the middle

Tags: recursion, f#

```
let  shuffley (numbers:int list) =
    let rec loop numbers acc =
        match numbers with
        | head::tail -> loop (List.rev(tail)) (head::acc)
        | [] -> List.rev(acc)
    loop numbers []
shuffley [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]
```

I am trying to practice some F# and I was wondering if could be a good example of tail recursion or this is just some nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this algorithm *is* tail recursive lets tackle another problem: having recursion instead of loops often makes it easier to reason about a single step but more difficult to see whether one step is (partially) undoing effects of the previous one.

Here, the remaining `numbers` are `rev`ersed in every step. This is an *O(n)* operation (*n = length of the list*), doing this in every step means the overall complexity is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

It seems the result could also be computed by

1. splitting the list into `a, b`
2. interleaving `a` and the `rev`ersed `b`

For splitting in linear time, there is a 'trick': moving two 'pointers' while keeping track of the visited elements (`acc`). The second pointer (`ys`) always skips two elements while the first one (`xs`) skips just one. The function needs to be called with `(input, input)`, i.e. both pointers at the first element:

```
let rec split acc = 
    function 
    | x :: xs, _ :: _ :: ys -> split (x :: acc) (xs, ys)
    | x :: xs, [_] -> split (x :: acc) (xs, [])
    | xs, _ -> List.rev acc, xs
```

Interleaving is straightforward:

```
let rec interleave acc = 
    function 
    | h :: t, o -> interleave (h :: acc) (o, t)
    | [], h :: t -> interleave (h :: acc) (t, [])
    | [], [] -> List.rev acc
```

both functions are of linear complexity, combining them sequentially is *O(n)* still:

```
let shuffley' list = 
    let rec interleave acc = 
        function 
        | h :: t, o -> interleave (h :: acc) (o, t)
        | [], h :: t -> interleave (h :: acc) (t, [])
        | [], [] -> List.rev acc

    let rec split acc = 
        function 
        | x :: xs, _ :: _ :: ys -> split (x :: acc) (xs, ys)
        | x :: xs, [_] -> split (x :: acc) (xs, [])
        | xs, _ -> List.rev acc, xs

    let a, b = split [] (list, list)
    interleave [] (a, List.rev b)
```

On my machine, `shuffley [0..10000]` (10k) takes about the same time as `shuffley' [0..1000000]` (1M) (less than a second), whereas `shuffley [0..100000]` (100k) doesn't even terminate within a minute.

Note that we can now also `shuffley'` any list, not just `int`s (due to the removed type annotations). If you want to pass an empty list in F# interactive, just use `shuffley' ([] : int list)`.

I reversed the accumulator and 'real' parameters to make use of the concise `function`ality.